# Help Creating a Dummy Data Set and Regressing Against It

Tags: poisson-regression

So I'm studying up on Poisson regressions and my first thought was to create a dummy dataset, then test linear and Poisson regressions against it to understand the difference.

My SAS code to create the dummy set:

> %let N = 10;
>   %let factor = 100;
>
> data Sample;
>
> call streaminit(4321);
>
> do i = 1 to &N;
>
> ```
>   spend = rand("Uniform");
>
>   visits = rand("Poisson",spend*&factor);
>
>   output;
> ```
>
> end;
>   run;

My regression SAS:

```
proc glm data=sample alpha=.05;
class weekend;
model visits = weekend spend / solution;
lsmeans weekend / cl;
output out=Linear predicted=Prediction lcl=LowerCL ucl=UpperCL residual=Residual;
run;

proc genmod data=sample;
class weekend;
model visits = weekend spend / dist=poisson link=log;
lsmeans weekend / cl;
output out=PLog pred=Prediction lower=LowerCL upper=UpperCL resraw=Residual;
run;
```

So at least the confidence intervals make much more sense for the Poisson regression, which is what I would expect. However, the actual predictions for the Poisson regression get very poor as Factor gets large. Doing a simple MSE on both shows that POisson underperforms the linear predictions substantially. I've tested this at various N's and Factors.

So,

1. Have I set up my dummy data right? Do I appear to be using genmod
   correctly?
2. Am I misunderstanding the value of the Poisson
   regression?
3. Shouldn't it provide a better model fit than the linear
   regression for any Factor (lamda)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Part of the reason may be that you're using the log link function in proc genmod while the true model uses the identity link, so your Poisson model is misspecified.  If you want to see how the model performs when it agrees with the true data generating process then set the mean of the Poisson to be $\exp(\text{spend} \cdot \text{factor})$.

Comment: Yup, that definitely makes the model make more sense, thank you dsaxton. I actually thought I had tried that, but must have done it incorrectly.

But let me ask then, given the way I originally set up the dataset, what's the right way to analyze it? I tried using a poisson distribution with an identity link, but that failed, and I assumed it's because it didn't make any sense to do that.

Comment: (by the way, there's a "Class weekend" in the analysis that doesn't mean anything anymore; I'll add that factor back once I have a better hold on what I'm doing)

Comment: I'm not sure why the identity link would fail because that's the true model.  What exactly went wrong?

Comment: This question seems to be about statistical confusions at least as much as coding ones. IMO, it could stay open here.

Comment: When I use the identity link it says:

>WARNING: The specified model did not converge.
>ERROR: The mean parameter is either invalid or at a limit of its range for some observations.

And honestly, I don't know what it means to have an identity link with the Poisson distribution. Like gung says, this is definitely about statistical confusions ;)

Comment: Sorry about the edits, I keep hitting enter too soon.

As a side note, I can work through the math of why the log link is the canonical link for the Poisson distribution. However, that hasn't seemed to impart much understanding. So thanks for your patience.

Comment: I've gotten the GENMOD Poisson with identity link to converge under some situations, and I'm starting to see a little better what's going on here. Although I'm not sure yet why it doesn't converge in all situations.

Comment: This concerns R, not SAS, but I still think it was still helpful to me:

https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Marschner.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As dsaxton pointed out, the model in the original question is simply misspecified and therefore provides poor results in some domains (large lambda). One solution is to use the identity link instead of the log link. I originally tried this and when the series didn't converge, assumed it was a bad idea.

I'm probably not the first noobie to do this, but I assumed that the canonical link is the best link. That's not necessarily true - the canonical link has many good properties, assuming it actually reflects the relationship in the data. In this case it did not.

Of course, not using the canonical link (identity instead) was correct, but led to difficulties getting a solution. It worked for some lamdas, but not others. This is another topic altogether that I'll research, but the original question has been answered.